Can no longer access "children", "value" and "formattedValue" fields within a slot override component in the v7 mui-x-datagrid
I've recently upgraded the mui-x-data-grid to v7 from v6. We had an override for the cell slot:
<Datagrid slots={{cell: CellBase}} />
In which we could access value, formattedValue, and children from the props passed down:
export const CellBase = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, GridCellProps>((props, ref) => { 
  // const { value, formattedValue, children } = props; 
  ...


But those properties no longer exist on the GridCellProps interface for v7, and I haven't found anything in the migration docs.
How do you access these properties properly in v7?

Here I faced the same problem as we were also relying on the incoming props of the custom cell implementation that we had. So I found this (https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v6/#filtering) while going through their migration guide.
apparently we have to now use the apiRef to access these information going forward.

Yeah, unfortunately in our case we needed access to the children, and to render them conditionally as a child of the MUI GridCell component, which seems to no longer be possible.

Ours was a somewhat specific use case, but we were able to access all of the same props as before by switching from the cell slot to a wrapper in the renderCell method in our column definitions.
export const authorColumns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'Actions',
    ...
    renderCell: props => (
      <CellBase {...props}>
        <ActionsCell {...props} />
      </CellBase>
    ),
    ...
  },
  ...
]


